# Javascript date acting strange

Tags: javascript

Why does this give me september 30 rather than oct 1?

```js
var dob = new Date("1999-10-01")
console.log(dob.toString())
```

Comment: because you did not specify a timezone.

Comment: It's taking it off your local system time. for me it's BST so shows as GMT+1

Comment: You're using a non-standard date format, so you're lucky it gives you a date instance at all. It's probably interpreting your date string as a UTC date/time and you're somewhere a few hours behind UTC.

Comment: it give me Fri Oct 01 1999 02:00:00 GMT+0200 : maybe it deals with local  timezone  ?

Comment: It issue of timeZone. It is taking timezone of your local system. Specify a time zone and it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, I'll look into this

Comment: As @Pointy pointed out the string is indeed parsed as UTC. I assume you want it parsed in your local time? This worked for me `(new Date(1999, 10 - 1, 1)).toString()` or `(new Date("1999-10-01 00:00:00")).toString()`

Comment: Actually looking again it's *not* non-standard (don't know what I was thinking), it's an ISO date, and if you leave out the time and time zone midnight UTC is assumed.

Comment: @Pointy The format is standard [ISO86001](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a Date `new Date("1999-10-01")` and parsing it with the method `toString()` which is using your local timezone:

```js
var dob = new Date("1999-10-01")

console.log(dob)
console.log(dob.toISOString())

console.log('My local time is different!')
console.log(dob.toLocaleString('es-AR', { timeZone: 'America/Buenos_Aires', timeZoneName: 'long'}))

console.log('Your local time is different?')
console.log(dob.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

The format you are using is a subset of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
When no timezone designator is specified offset Zulu (UTC) is implied in the date constructor.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15

> All numbers must be base 10. If the MM or DD fields are absent “01” is
>   used as the value. If the HH, mm, or ss fields are absent “00” is used
>   as the value and the value of an absent sss field is “000”. The value
>   of an absent time zone offset is “Z”.

In other words, the format that you are using is valid and it denotes a date-time in UTC. What you are seeing in the console is that time represented in your timezone.

```js
const date = new Date("1999-10-01");

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('ar-EG'));
console.log(date.toString());
console.log(date.toISOString());
```